# Vector based binary tree traversal

Tags: c++, vector, binary-tree, traversal, preorder

I have a vector based binary tree and need to apply a function to each value in the tree using various methods of traversal. The preorder traversal was very easy to implement with a recursive function but I have been having trouble doing the same with the inorder and postorder traversals. If anyone could help out that would be great!

Some extra information that I should have included:
I am using a vector of nodes, each node containing a boolean variable stating whether or not that node is filled and a templated data variable. Each node is stored at an index "i" while its left child is at the index "2i+1" and the right child at "2i+2".

To apply a preorder traversal to the list, I first processed the data stored at index 0 and then called this recursive function

```
template <typename Item, typename Key>
template <typename Function>
void BST<Item,Key>::preTraverse(int n, Function f) {
    if(tree[n].occupied == false) return;
    else {
        f(tree[n].data);
        preTraverse(2*i+1,f);
        preTraverse(2*i+2,f);
    }
}
```

twice beginning with indices 1 & 2 as my "n" parameter.

Comment: Could you please post the code of the traversal that you managed to get right? This will help us better understand the way that you used to "fold" a tree in a vector.

Comment: Is the vector representation effectively a max-populated left-to-right definition? (i.e. children of [i] are at [2i+1] and [2i+2] ?

Comment: "*preorder traversal was easy ... but I [have trouble] with the preorder ... traversal*"? Perhaps you didn't say what you meant to say.

Comment: I added the code and more details of the vector in an edit to the question. I also meant to say inorder and postorder rather than preorder and postorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your tree is a max-populated left-dominant representation, then any given point in your array at position `i` will have children at positions `2*i+1` and `2*i+2`. The trivial walk:

```
Node   Children
=====  ===========
ar[0]: ar[1], ar[2]
ar[1]: ar[3], ar[4]
ar[2]: ar[5], ar[6]
ar[3]: ar[7], ar[8]
ar[4]: ar[9], ar[10] etc...
```

Given this definition, preorder, postorder, and in-order can all be done with simple index forwarding and some checks for your 'occupied' flag. The following templates assume type `T` is a structure type that has an 'occupied' member.

```
template<typename T>
void preorder(const T ar[], size_t i, size_t count, void (&visit)(const T&))
{
    if (i>=count || !ar[i].occupied)
        return;

    visit(ar[i]);
    preorder(ar, 2*i+1, count, visit);
    preorder(ar, 2*(i+1), count, visit);
}

template<typename T>
void inorder(const T ar[], size_t i, size_t count, void (&visit)(const T&))
{
    if (i>=count || !ar[i].occupied)
        return;

    inorder(ar, 2*i+1, count, visit);
    visit(ar[i]);
    inorder(ar, 2*(i+1), count, visit);
}

template<typename T>
void postorder(const T ar[], size_t i, size_t count, void (&visit)(const T&))
{
    if (i>=count || !ar[i].occupied)
        return;

    postorder(ar, 2*i+1, count, visit);
    postorder(ar, 2*(i+1), count, visit);
    visit(ar[i]);
}
```

Comment: your postorder function is wrong, it should be ``postorder(ar, 2*i+1, visit);``, ``postorder(ar, 2*i+2, visit);`` and then ``visit(ar[i]);``

Answer (score 3):

preorder:

```
do something with the value
f(go to the left)
f(go to the right)
```

inorder:

```
f(go to the left)
do something with the value
f(go to the right)
```

postorder:

```
f(go to the left)
f(go to the right)
do something with the value
```