# Represent and traverse a n-ary tree as a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, tree, trie

I've implemented a n-ary tree ( to be more specific, a trie ) and I was wondering if there's a method to represent and traverse it as a vector. With a binary tree that would be trivial ( see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557469/vector-based-binary-tree-traversal) ) but I don't seem to find a way to perform this with a n-ary tree.
My final goal would be storing the vector represented tree to a file, mmap it and perform fast lookups without having it effectively loaded into memory.
An efficient approach to store a trie on disk ad using it with a mmap-ped pointer instead of allocating its inner structures would be great too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a tree where every node n has exactly k children, then you can proceed by placing the children of node n at positions k*n+m in the array, where m is between 0 and k-1. This will also work if every node has k or less children, but it will use a lot more memory than required if a lot of nodes have fewer than k children. The only other way I know of to store a tree as an array where nodes have different number of children is to store an auxillary array,, where for each node you store the offset into the original array to find that node's children and then you can either also store the number of children for each node or simply look up the offset for the next node's children to figure out how many children there are for the node.

Comment: Exactly what I came up with, just keep the offsets and use them as node pointers to jmp accross the file, but this seemed a slow solution to me so I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Any graph structure can be represented as a flat array of nodes (in fact, that's how computer memory works). You just need to use indices instead of pointers, because pointers are invalidated when the `vector` grows or when the structure is `mmap`'d.

Here's a three-way tree as a flat `vector`:

```
struct Node {
    Node(int data) : payload(data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            child[i] = (size_t)(-1);  // invalid
        }
    }

    int payload;
    size_t child[3];
};

typedef std::vector<Node> Tree;

void add_node(Tree &t, size_t parent, int child_index, int payload)
{
    t.push_back(Node(payload));
    t[parent].child[child_index] = t.size() - 1;
}
```

You'll need separate logic to insert the root node since it doesn't have a parent. Also if you want a version where the `mmap`'d files can be used cross-platform, you'd better use fixed-size index types rather than the platform-specific `int` and `size_t`.

Traversal code is the same as with a pointer structure, except that

```
next = node->child[1]
```

becomes

```
t[t[node_idx].child[1]]
```

etc. i.e. each lookup of a node passes through the `Tree` object.

Comment: in your example you have a constant number of children ( 3 ), what if every node could have a variable number of children ( a trie for instance ) ? If you should serialize each node, how could you "jump" from node A to node D if there're B and C in between and their size is not constant ( since they could have any number of children ) ?

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli In a trie you have a fixed number of children, the elements of your alphabet, or just 256 if you stipulate that all inputs are byte strings. (For compression, you could actually treat them as half-byte strings, store 16 children and just double the number of nodes.)

Comment: It would also be very simple to `template`-ize these structure as `template<typename T, unsigned N> struct Node {...`

Comment: @larsmans yep the standard implementation is with `Node *children[256]` but I use a linked list, growing it when needed, each Node is a `struct { uint8_t value; void *data; ll_t children; }` ... less memory used :)

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli Depends on how dense the trie is and on the quality of your memory allocator. Note that a single link requires 16 bytes in this setup on an x86-64 plus overhead from the memory allocator. I would at least use a vector for that. Again, with appropriate bit-fiddling, you can reduce the number of children to 16 per node.

Comment: Isn't the pointer array 1024 bytes big? 4*256 (on 32 bit layout) 1K for each node is too much in my case, the sparse implementation is the only doable

Comment: @SimoneMargaritelli In the normal case, yes. Maybe you should look at [double-array tries](http://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/datrie.html) for compression a scheme.

Comment: Will take a look to this implementation, if I can keep the number of children a constant, then the solution to my problem is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the No of node of the tree

you could change the size of adj vector to your suitable value

code->

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> adj[100000000];
void dfs(int);
int main()
{

    int i,n,root,par;
    cin>>n;
     //Input line contains n space separated integers.
    // The ith integer represents the immediate ancestor of the ith node
   // Node having 0 as parent node is the Root Node
    i=1;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        cin>>par;

        if(par==0)
        {
            root=i;
        }
        else
        {
            adj[par].push_back(i);
        }
        i++;
    }
    //traversal of the Tree(Inorder traversal)
   dfs(root);

    }

    void dfs(int at)
   {
vector<int>::iterator it;
it=adj[at].begin();
cout<<*it<<" ";
while(it!=adj[at].end())
{
    dfs((*it));
    it++;
}
return;
}
```

Hoping this might helps